# Inkscape font different from other platforms

Tags: fonts, inkscape, font-design

When I'm using the font `Segoe Script` in Inkscape, the characters vary depending on where they are positioned in the word. I tried using the same font in CorelDraw and Microsoft Word, but they don't have the same behavior as in Inkscape.

[Click here to download the Inkscape version](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/micaelbatista/stackoverflow-134000/master/font_inkscape_version.svg)

[Click here to download the MS Word version](https://github.com/micaelbatista/stackoverflow-134000/raw/master/font_msword_version.docx)

Here is an example of what I'm talking about:

[image]

In the majority of the characters, the "tail" in the end of it shows up in word but not in Inkscape. Pay special attention to the `y` and `u` characters, which change the most depending on where they are in the word.

I'd like to use the Inkscape version of the `Segoe Script` font in other softwares, but I'm not sure how to make them behave like this. Or at least understand why Inkscape is doing this but not the remaining softwares like MS Word and CorelDraw.

Comment: The font is an OpenType font with advanced features such as contextual ligatures and alternates. I think you need to switch that feature on in Word - it's not enabled by default.  I don't use Word. Sorry. Try googling "enable opentype contextual ligatures in word".

Comment: Yup, that was it. I found an article saying how to enable it in Word and Photoshop here: https://medialoot.com/blog/how-to-enable-opentype-features-in-word-photoshop-and-illustrator/ . Create an answer with your comment and I'll accept it, thanks!

Comment: OK, I've added it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The font is an OpenType font with advanced features such as contextual ligatures and alternates. I think you need to switch that feature on in Word - it's not enabled by default. I don't use Word. Sorry. Try googling "enable opentype contextual ligatures in word".